# Does the JR East pass cover my route?

Tags: japan, tokyo, japan-rail

I will be staying in Tokyo for about 12/13 days or so in May and need to work out which pass, between the full JR pass and the JR East pass is better for me.

My full day trips outside of Tokyo are as follows:

- Mt. Fuji
- Sendai
- Tokyo DisneySea
- Kamakura
- Nikko
- Nagoya

The JR east pass is £137 and lasts for any 5 days of my choosing during my travel period (not necessarily consecutive days).

The JR pass is £165 and lasts for 7 consecutive days.

Of course the flexibility with the first one is nice, but the extra 2 days with the latter is good too. Now, the places I've listed are not specifically stated that they work with the JR East pass, but if it does and it could save me money I would rather go for this option obviously. Of course, the extra 2 days I would have with the main pass I'm assuming I could use for the transport links in and around Tokyo.

Does the JR East pass covers the area I wish to visit?

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: @Geeo Sorry, should have been more clear. I am not sure which of the locations are covered by which pass, so I am asking if anyone else knows before I make my decision.

Comment: I edited the question for you, let me know if it fits your needs or I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Apparently, with your current route, you cannot benefit much from the JR East pass.

The [official site](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/eastpass/) has a pretty handy map which shows exactly what part is covered and what kind of trains you can choose from.

[image]

> Unlimited travel on local, limited express and express trains
>   including Shinkansens on the following rail company lines:
>   JR East Lines (including BRT*)
>   Izu Kyuko Line
>   Hokuetsu Kyuko Railway Hokuhoku Line
>   Aoimori Railway
>   IGR Iwate Galaxy Railway
>   Tokyo Monorail
>   Sendai Airport Transit Tokyo Waterfront Area Rapid Transit Rinkai Line
>   The following limited express trains that directly run between the JR East
>   lines and Tobu Railway lines:
>   the Nikko, the Spacia Nikko, the Kinugawa, and the Spacia Kinugawa.
>   Also, the local trains (including rapid trains) between Shimo-imaichi and Tobu > nikko/Kinugawa-onsen Stations.
>   Notes:
>   * Bus rapid transit. The JR EAST PASS is not valid for the Tokaido Shinkansen as that is operated by a different rail company. The JR
>   EAST PASS is not valid for JR buses.

Judging from the [interactive route map](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/routemaps/index.html) you cannot reach Fuji, Kamakura, Nagoya. You can reach Nikko tho.

I don't know how strict your plan is but I would consider buying the JR pass (full) because it gives you way more flexibility and it's not much more expensive than the east only pass.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone with the JR pass - for the ease of mind if nothing else :) .

Comment: Welcome. bear in mind that you can also use the JR Pass for the Yamanote [山手線] and Chūō [中央] line inside Tokyo, very handy if you don't wanna spend a lot of money using the subway.